# java calculate time between two timestamps

Tags: java, android, time, timestamp, date-arithmetic

I need to calculate the time passed between two dates.

The catch here is that I need to show it as YouTube does with its video comments timestamps. That is, to show it by just the largest measure.

For example,

- if the time is 50 seconds ago it should say 50 seconds ago.
- if the time is more than one minute it should say one minute ago/ten minutes ago etc..
- if the time difference is 1 hour 30 mins it should show: an hour ago.
- if the time is one and a half week than it should say one week ago.
- if the time is more than a month it should say one month ago/two months ago etc...
- and so on and so on..

So what is the best way to handle this?
Should I make a method with `case` or `if` statements that would return something like this? Or is there a better approach (maybe a library which already does something like it)?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use [DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(long time, long now, long minResolution)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeTimeSpanString%28long,%20long,%20long%29). `time` is the start time, and `now` is the end time (in milliseconds). To report "seconds ago," set minResolution to zero.

Example:

```
String result = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(1306767830, 1306767835, 0);
// result = "5 seconds ago"
```

Comment: Perfect answer, but the return-type is **CharSequence**, not **String**. So, either change **result** type to **CharSequence**, or type-cast it.

Comment: how do i get the number of days between two timestamps ?

Comment: Perfect answer!

Answer (score 5):

```
 date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()
```

This will return you the time in miliseconds between the 2 dates. Just convert that to what ever you want to show (e.g. hours minutes seconds)

Comment: ok this i know how to do... this gets me time in miliseconds and not in the format i want to create it in... My question was regarding how to proceed to get the result described in my question. what is the right/simplest way to do it...

Answer (score 3):

On Android, use this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeTimeSpanString%28android.content.Context,%20long,%20boolean%29

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [PrettyTime](http://ocpsoft.com/prettytime/)!

Also, everytime you want to do something date/time-related in Java, you should take a look at [Joda Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/). Do it now, you will thank me later.

Answer (score 0):

Your need is very specific, and I don't know any lib that would solve the problem for you out of the box.
However the problem is not very complex and a small function full of "ifs" should do the trick.
Of course, a nice date library like Joda Time will help you keep your code clean. Who wants to use GregorianCalendar!?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you have a set of custom rules and the algorithm to choose a rule is based on the time in seconds between two timestamps. The easiest approach is to handle the *rules* in a series of if/else if statements:

```
 private String getTimeAsString(int seconds) {
   if (seconds < 60) {     // rule 1
      return String.format("%s seconds ago", seconds);
   } else if (seconds < 3600) {  // rule 2
      return String.format("%s minutes ago", seconds/60);
   } // ... and so on
 }
```