# Calculate difference in time (between current and next day)

Tags: java, android

There is a lot of similar topics but I couldn't find something similar then my problem. I've found only how to calculate if for example second time is greater then first time, like:

1. 22:00
2. 23:00

The result is easy to get. Just subtract second time with first using Date API. Difference is in milliseconds and you can easily convert them in seconds/minutes..

What I want to know, how to get difference between time in first day and time in second day, for example:

1. 22:25
2. 06:30

Difference should be 8 hours and 5 minutes.

Or another example

1. 19:00
2. 00:00

Difference should be 5 hours.

How to calculate time in this way? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you don't know the dates, the answer is ambiguous. But you could do the subtraction and then modulo-24 the answer... Thus if (a-b)<0, add 24.

Comment: Convert the 2 dates to milliseconds, subtract the 2 milliseconds and convert it back to date? Oh, you might want to do the abs() of 2 numbers if the value is less than zero.

Comment: Do you always know that the second time is the next day? Or could they be the same day.

Comment: have a look in to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5132698/1329126

Comment: @Sankar V, I think the OP wants it in hours/minutes/seconds and not days.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi just need to modify the last line in that code to convert it to hours/minutes/seconds whatever. Am I right?

Comment: @Sankar V, for each time unit, you will have to do your calculation (so a repeated calculation from the last line of code).

Answer (score 1):

Convert your date and time to TimeStamp (It's just the long representation of a date in milliseconds since Jan. 1, 1970.), then calculate difference, and transferred from milliseconds to hours.

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177830/java-calculate-time-between-two-timestamps)

Answer (score 0):

Use Calendar class. Set your day, hour and minutes and finally subtract those dates (in milliseconds) and you will convert result in hour, minutes and seconds.